# stepping into msvcr100d.dll has stopped working after VS 2010 SP1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

It appears that I can no longer step into run time library calls. This used to work before SP1, now it only prints, e.g.:

```
'thread_test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'thread_test.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
```

Searching using Google has not revealed anything...revealing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed as suggested by http://qualapps.blogspot.com/2007/04/symbols-for-mfc-source-code.html:

1. Add directory "C:\Windows\Symbols\dll" to the beginning of the symbols list.
2. Clear symbols cache directory.

Comment: Can't add to beginning! The interface doesn't allow me!

Comment: @sergiol: It does not have to be at the very beginning. It would probably work if it were anywhere in the list, I think.